# Collapse ContainerViews and adjust position dynamically in iOS Swift 2.x

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, uicontainerview

I created a ViewController in my Storyboard which has 2 containerViews. Those 2 containerViews were added programmatically.

ContainerView 1 - has a SearchBarController. Right below is the ContainerView 2.
ContainerView 2 - has a TableViewController

I implemented a collapse function for the SearchBarController and the ContainerView.

When i collapse my Searchbar, i want my ContainerView 2 containing the TableViewController to take the now freed space and move up. When expanding the Searchbar, i want my ContainerView 2 and the TableViewController to make place for the searchbar it again.

I expect the solution to be: ContainerView2 has an auto layout constraint that keeps a certain distance to ContainerView1. But I do not know how to achieve that. I would be glad if someone could provide a snippet how to set up the auto layout constraint programatically or maybe a link to a tutorial. Thank you!

Comment: Can you use a stack view? That's probably the easiest way.